# How to get average of a column per block of data in python

Tags: python, pandas

Here is an example of the data I am dealing with:

[image]

This example of data is a shortened version of each Run. Here the runs are about 4 rows long. In a typical data set they are anywhere between 50-100 rows long. There are also 44 different runs.

So my goal is to get the average of the last 4 rows a given column in stage 2, right now I am achieving that, but it grabs the average based on these conditions for the whole spreadsheet. I want to be able to get these average values for each and every 'Run'.

```
df["Run"] = pd.DataFrame({
    "Run": ["Run1.1", "Run1.2", "Run1.3", "Run2.1", "Run2.2", "Run2.3", "Run3.1", "Run3.2", "Run3.3", "Run4.1",
            "Run4.2", "Run4.3", "Run5.1", "Run5.2", "Run5.3", "Run6.1", "Run6.2", "Run6.3", "Run7.1", "Run7.2",
            "Run7.3", "Run8.1", "Run8.2", "Run8.3", "Run9.1", "Run9.2", "Run9.3", "Run10.1", "Run10.2", "Run10.3",
            "Run11.1", "Run11.2", "Run11.3"],
})
av = df.loc[df['Stage'].eq(2),'Vout'].groupby("Run").tail(4).mean()

print(av)
```

I want to be able to get these averages for a given column that is in Stage 2, based on each and every 'Run'. As you can see before each data set there is a corresponding 'Run' e.g the second data set has 'Run1.2' before it.

Also, each file I am dealing with, the amount of rows per Run is different/not always the same.

So, it is important to note that this is not achievable with `np.repeat`, as with each new sheet of data, the rows can be any length, not just the same as the example above.

Expected output:

```
Run1.1 1841 (example value)
Run1.2 1703 (example value)
Run1.3 1390 (example value)
... so on
```

etc

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Save which run a row belongs to in a column instead of a seperate row. Then you can use `groupby()` and `mean` to get the mean per run

Answer (score 0):

What does your panda df look like after you import the csv?

I would say you can just `groupby` on the run column like such:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    "run": ["run1.1", "run1.2", "run1.1", "run1.2"],
    "data": [1, 2, 3, 4],
})

df.groupby("run").agg({"data": ["sum"]}).head()
```

```
Out[4]: 
       data
        sum
run        
run1.1    4
run1.2    6
```

Comment: I have updated the post, I am struggling to implement ```groupby```

Answer (score 0):

This will do the trick:

```py
av = df.loc[df["Stage"].eq(2)]
av = av.groupby("Run").tail(4).groupby("Run")["Vout"].mean()
```

Now `df.groupby("a").tail(n)` will return dataframe with only last `n` elements for each value of `a`. Then the second `groupby` will just aggregate these and return average per group.

Comment: With this, I am only getting some rows returned. I ran this code on a larger data set with up to 40 runs. I only got back runs 2-5. Why would this be?